How to make C++ container class store pointer to a const, but get as a non-const?
I have the some code similar to the following.  This is obviously a stripped-down version.
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    Foo() : bar(0) {}
};

class Container {
    Foo* foo;
    
    public:
        void put(const Foo* in_foo) {
            foo = in_foo;
        }
        
        Foo* get() {
            return foo;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Container c;
    
    c.put(&foo);
    
    Foo* pFoo = c.get();
    pFoo->bar = 3;
}

Running this, I get an error message:

main.cpp: In member function ‘void Container::put(const Foo*)’:
main.cpp:20:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Foo*’ to ‘Foo*’
[-fpermissive]

See https://onlinegdb.com/2SrlyGdQY .
I want to "promise" that I'm not going to mess with Foo when putting into my container, but not force Foo to be a const when the user gets it back out.  What's the best way to handle this?

I want to "promise" that I'm not going to mess with Foo when putting into my container, but not force Foo to be a const when the user gets it back out. What's the best way to handle this? This doesn't make any sense. You promise you don't mess with Foo but you want to be able to mess with it when you get it out. Choose one.

The compiler is trying to help you and you want to know hot to disable those safety measures. Just don't do that. Why do you think you need to do that? What are you trying to achieve with it? With that context info, someone here will be able to figure out how to implement it properly. That said, the answer to your question is const_cast, but that is not a solution to your problem!

When a method takes a const argument, the promise is that it will never by changed by the object, and that at any moment. You should think twice about the const requirements of your class...

You have conflicting requirements. The objects are either constant or they're not.

why do you want to declare something that you want to modify as const?

Hmm, OK.  So other than using const_cast, you all are saying that it doesn't make sense for my Container class to promise it's not going to change the internal data of Foo when storing it.  That seems too permissive.  I want Container to be a storage-only class.  My real code is actually storing an array of Foo.  The user of Container should feel confident that Container is not going to change Foo.

@UlrichEckhardt, the context is that I'm in a real-time environment, and I cannot use the STL.  I have a class called FiniteMap<class T, int S> that stores up to S T objects in an internal array.  The user can assign an arbitrary key to each T and use put and get methods to store and retrieve the object.  The key is hashed into the internal array index for storage.  Again, I just want the user to be confident that FiniteMap is not going to change T in any of its methods.

Look at std::vector or any other standard container class. Do they ever modify objects? No¹. Do they do any weird shenanigans with const to prove that? Also no. You don't have to express everything with the language, it's perfectly fine to document "This class will not modify any objects passed in" and people will believe until proven otherwise. ¹They can move objects, which does modify them, but that is very rarely visible to the outside. And move semantics on themselves are enough to make const type in container a bad idea.

"I want to "promise" that I'm not going to mess with Foo", but then you allow c.get()->bar = 3;. So you break your promise.

It's not the container that users should be worried about. Just provide const qualified accessors to FiniteMap that returns const T& and then all const FiniteMaps will provide const access to the contained elements. Btw, what's the difference between a FiniteMap and a std::array? The element count isn't always S I guess?

@TedLyngmo that's correct.  I want to map an arbitrary integer to an object.  Not necessarily a sequential integer, and I only want to allow the user to store S of them, but the key can be any unique integer.

I've made a similar specialized map for a limited set of keys myself so it's not that I don't see the need. What you should do is to make it feel much like a standard container and perhaps one of the new ones like std::flat_map can provide some inspiration for the API.

The best way is to change the member variable to Foo const* foo; and change the getter to Foo const* get() { return foo; }.  If the user decides to mess with it after they get it out of the Container that's on their shoulders.


I want to "promise" that I'm not going to mess with Foo when putting into my container, but not force Foo to be a const when the user gets it back out. What's the best way to handle this?

OK. First consider what std::vector would do. std::vector<Foo>::push_back(value) stores a copy of value in the container. More formally:

Appends the given element value to the end of the container. The new element is initialized as a copy of value.

Storing pointers in std::vector does not change much. Neither push_back nor any other method dereferences one of the pointers in a std::vector<Foo*> or std::vector<const Foo*>. The "promise" to not do weird / silly / unexpected stuff is implicit. If push_back would modify elements or use a pointer to modify other stuff it would be broken.

Next, consider what issues would arise if you could turn a const Foo* easily into a Foo*:
class BrokenContainer {
    Foo* foo;        
    public:
        void put(const Foo* in_foo) { magic(foo,in_foo); }
        Foo* get() { return foo; }
};

int main() {
    const Foo foo;        // const !
    BrokenContainer c;
    c.put(&foo);          // ok
    Foo* pFoo = c.get();  // ok?
    pFoo->bar = 3;        // no!
}

The (implicit) promise a Foo* get() makes to the user is: "If you passed me a valid pointer to put then the pointer returned from get can be used to modify the pointee". Hence any magic would surprisingly break user code.

You may have heard about const_cast. It cannot solve the issue illustrated above, it's the tool to create the mess.
Really the only case where you would cast const away is when you just added the const (for more details see How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?). Any attempt to remove const across interfaces breaks const correctness and will end in tears (there is just no way to tell from a const Foo* whether it points to a constant or non-constant Foo).

You want a class that stores a pointer to a Foo. A user of the class can retrieve that pointer to modify the Foo. The way to express that is:
class Container {
    Foo* foo;
    public:
        void put(Foo* in_foo) { foo = in_foo; }          
        Foo* get() { return foo; }
};

A "Container" is not expected to mess with what it contains. If the user wants to retrieve a pointer to a modifiable Foo they need to pass one.

The problem is that when you assign foo to in_foo in the put function you are assigning a immutable struct to a mutable one. Therefore if you pass in a struct with the value bar of 0 you can then after change that same struct (which foo and in_foo both point to) to 3.
Here you are not passing in a immutable struct, you want to be able to change it. So I would recommended to just pass in a Foo* and not make it const. However if you really want to promise that put will not change the struct in_foo points to you can change foo = in_foo to foo = const_cast<Foo*>(in_foo).
However this is not recommended and is only safe to do if the passed in in_foo will always be mutable. However you cannot guarantee this and therefore you should not do this.
There isn't really a best or good way to do this. I would change the parameter of put to a Foo* especially since put() is such a concise function and you can see that in_foo is not modified.

What if the user put s in a pointer to a Foo that is actually declared const and you start providing non-const access to it? This feels fragile...

Yes this is why it is not a goof idea to do so. Unless you are always passing in a Foo* and not a const Foo*. However you cannot guarantee this.
